Connecting a k3s agent via another agent's control plane
I'm attempting to prove out some k3s architecture and part of that is to be able to logically isolate some k3s agents from others. I don't want to go into too much detail, but it is basically following an ISA95 network segmentation and isolation.
What I'm trying to achieve is have a k3s agent in a "lower" network segment, connect to the control plane via an agent in the network segment directly above. Something like this two-second diagram (note: I've stripped out a lot of complexity here just isolate the problem)

It seems like this is possible in a variety of ways and what I'm looking for is what is the most natural way I can achieve this
From what I've researched so far, I could host my own nginx (or similar) reverse proxy and forward the traffic upstream from there, but from what I can tell, this comes with a downside of requiring extra custom TLS certificates. I could be wrong here, maybe there is away to use the inbuilt certs to host the proxy?
Another option is to use the built-in ingress controller and forward the control plane https/443 traffic to the next agent or server. This seems like the most 'native' way to do this, as it presumably removes the custom certificate option, however I'm wondering if there are any other ways that I haven't come across yet?
